# Linux and Hadoop : Mounting a disk and increasing the cluster capacity

Tags: linux, hadoop

First of all, I'm a total noob at hadoop and linux.I have a cluster of five nodes , which when starts shows a each node capacity only 46.6 GB while each machine had around 500 gb space which i dont know how to allocate to these nodes.

(1) Do I have to change the datanode and namenode file size(i checked these and it shows the same space remaining as in the Datanode information tab)? if so how should i do that.

(2)Also this 500gb disk is only shown when i do $lsblk command and not when i do $df -H command. Does that mean its not mounted? These are the results of the commands. Can someone explain what does this mean..

```
[hadoop@hdp1 hadoop]$ sudo lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                          11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sda                           8:0    0   50G  0 disk 
\u251c\u2500sda1                        8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
\u2514\u2500sda2                        8:2    0 49.5G  0 part 
  \u251c\u2500VolGroup-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 47.6G  0 lvm  /
  \u2514\u2500VolGroup-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                           8:16   0  512G  0 disk 

[hadoop@hdp1 hadoop]$ sudo df -H
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       51G  6.7G   41G  15% /
tmpfs                  17G   14M   17G   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             500M  163M  311M  35% /boot
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.
First can someone help me understand why its showing different memory disks and what it means and where does it reside ?! I seem to not able to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Your second disk (sdb) is not mounted anywhere. If you are going to dedicate the whole disk to hadoop data, here is how you should format and mount it:

Format your disk:

```
mkfs.ext4 -m1 -O dir_index,extent,sparse_super /dev/sdb
```

For mounting edit the file /etc/fstab. Add this line:

```
/dev/sdb    /hadoop/disk0   ext4    noatime 1 2
```

After that, create the directory /hadoop/disk0 (it doesn't have to be named like that. you could use a directory of your choice).

```
mkdir -p /hadoop/disk0
```

Now you are ready to mount the disk:

```
mount -a
```

Finally, you should let hadoop know that you want to use this disk as hadoop storage. Your /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml should contain these config parameters

```
<property><name>dfs.name.dir</name><value>/hadoop/disk0/nn</value></property>
<property><name>dfs.data.dir</name><value>/hadoop/disk0/dn</value></property>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton !! This totally worked ! I had to format the namenode after changing the config parameters and the cluster capacity totally increased. Thanks again :)

Comment: Unless you want to run into this issue https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1341873 - please use UUID in fstab. Also it will be better if you file system label so that you can identify the mountpoint from the label.